# Is there a way to replace only part of the value within a node using XSLT

Tags: xslt

I am attempting to replace only a portion of the value in a node. I've read a few of the articles here and they seem to replace the entire string.

Here's what I have;

```
<commands>
  <command>chmod 550 OLDPATH/system</command>
  <command>chmod 750 OLDPATH/system/config/home</command>
</commands>
```

Here's what I want;

```
<commands>
 <command>chmod 550 NEWPATH/system</command>
 <command>chmod 750 NEWPATH/system/config/home</command>
</commands>
```

Comment: What is the **exact** rule applied in your example? -- Please indicate your version of XSLT, too.

Answer (score 3):

Technically, you can't replace a part of anything in XSLT. However, when you are replacing the entire value of a node, you can use string functions to utilize parts of the value being replaced when building the new value.

For example, applying the following template to your example:

```
<xsl:template match="command">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., 'OLDPATH')" />
        <xsl:text>NEWPATH</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., 'OLDPATH')" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

would result in:

```
<command>chmod 550 NEWPATH/system</command>
<command>chmod 750 NEWPATH/system/config/home</command>
```